# finding the first row that is greater than the time offset for each row in sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with columns `timestamp`, `price`. I want to find whether the price went up or down after 1 second. The timestamp is in snowflake's TIMESTAMP_TZ format, i.e., `2022-12-12 9:30:00.0+01:00`.

If I were to do this using a for loop, it would look something like this:

```py
# pseudocode in python
price_diff = {}
for i in range(len(table)):
  current_row = table[i]
  for j in range(i, -1, -1):
     prev_row = table[j]
     if current_row.datetime - prev_row.datetime >= 1 second:
        price_diff[current_row.index] = current_row.price - prev_row.price
        break
```

Here's what I've tried:

```sql
SELECT table1.datetime, table1.price, 
(
  SELECT table2.price
  FROM mytable table2
  WHERE
  timediff(second, table1.datetime, table2.datetime) > 1 
  ORDER BY
  table2.datetime
  DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS price_tm1,
(table1.price - price_tm1) AS price_diff
FROM
mytable table1
```

This gives me an error saying:
`SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way it to use lead to get the "next" but this will only find when the inter message values is over 1 second, thus with this data:

```
with mytable(stock, datetime, price) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:45.00'::timestamp, 10.0),
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:45.01'::timestamp, 10.1),
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:45.02'::timestamp, 10.2),
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:48.00'::timestamp, 11.0)  
)
select *
    ,lead(datetime) over (partition by stock order by datetime) as lead_datetime
    ,lead(price) over (partition by stock order by datetime) as lead_price
    ,timediff(second, table1.datetime, lead_datetime) as gap
    ,iff(gap > 1, lead_price, null) as next_second_plus_price
from mytable as table1
order by datetime
;
```

| STOCK | DATETIME | PRICE | LEAD_DATETIME | LEAD_PRICE | GAP | NEXT_SECOND_PLUS_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:45.000 | 10 | 2022-12-13 12:31:45.010 | 10.1 | 0 | null |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:45.010 | 10.1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:45.020 | 10.2 | 0 | null |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:45.020 | 10.2 | 2022-12-13 12:31:48.000 | 11 | 3 | 11 |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:48.000 | 11 | null | null | null | null |

but if you really want the next per row, then you want to use a join, and the filter away the unwanted rows with a qualify:

```
with mytable(stock, datetime, price) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:45.00'::timestamp, 10.0),
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:45.01'::timestamp, 10.1),
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:45.02'::timestamp, 10.2),
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:46.00'::timestamp, 11.0),  
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:46.01'::timestamp, 11.1),  
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:46.02'::timestamp, 11.2),  
    (1, '2022-12-13 12:31:46.03'::timestamp, 11.3)  
)
select t1.*
    ,t2.datetime as next_datetime
    ,t2.price as next_price
from mytable as t1
left join mytable as t2
    on t1.stock = t2.stock and dateadd(second, 1, t1.datetime) < t2.datetime
qualify row_number() over (partition by t1.stock, t1.datetime order by t2.datetime) = 1
order by 1,2;
```

| STOCK | DATETIME | PRICE | NEXT_DATETIME | NEXT_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:45.000 | 10 | 2022-12-13 12:31:46.010 | 11.1 |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:45.010 | 10.1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:46.020 | 11.2 |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:45.020 | 10.2 | 2022-12-13 12:31:46.030 | 11.3 |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:46.000 | 11 | null | null |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:46.010 | 11.1 | null | null |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:46.020 | 11.2 | null | null |
| 1 | 2022-12-13 12:31:46.030 | 11.3 | null | null |

Comment: the second solution is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAG` function to get the value of datetime and price of the previous row (ordering the data on datetime) in the current row. It's then pretty straightforward to calculate the time and price difference.

You haven't specified what `price_diff` should be if the time difference is <= 1 second so I have set it to NULL in this example.

```
WITH base AS (
    SELECT 
          datetime
        , price
        , lag(datetime, 1) over (order by datetime) as prev_datetime
        , lag(price, 1) over (order by datetime) as prev_price
    FROM tableA
)
SELECT 
      datetime
    , price
    , prev_datetime
    , prev_price
    , CASE 
        WHEN datediff(second, prev_datetime, datetime) > 1
            THEN price - prev_price
        ELSE NULL 
      END AS price_diff
FROM base 
ORDER BY datetime
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Doesn't `LAG` only get the previous row? If there exists a row with `timediff > 1` that is 5 rows before the current row, the above query would set it as `NULL`, right?

Comment: LAG does get the previous row (or n rows previous depending on what is specified in the function). Based on your question it looked like that's what you wanted, if it isn't I suggest adding some more detail as it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MoneyBall if you're looking for a row with timediff > 1 that could be N rows before, then either N or a time interval need to be defined.